# Tag removal request: dehydratration

Tags: support

Seeing [an edit suggestion](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23963) for the tag [dehydratration](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dehydratration), made me consider adding the tag as a synonym of [dehydration](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dehydration) as that is the correct spelling but the system will not allow me to do so.

[image: screenshot of error]

Could someone with ◆ mod privileges please do something to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the notice. I've created it as a synonym and merged the tags.